# Video encoding (renderer): VP9, webM

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, file-format

Is it possible to encode video with VP9 and make webM videos? If so, how? The help doesn't include either in the list of formats/codecs.

Comment: These formats are not possible to export directly from Blender, as they are fairly obscure and specialized. You will need to use a special application to convert the video files you export to these formats. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about video encoding methods and is not about Blender.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise It actually is anout Blender, it's asking if Blender can export these formats.  The answer is no, so in my mind you should put that in an answer.  But I don't see why it should be closed just because the answer is no.

Comment: @PGmath I agree.

Comment: @PGmath, that is the question, but since it can't, it is off-topic, there have been questions closed in the same manner before. If you think it necessary, we should of course re-open it. I am not an advocate for closing as an end-all, quite the contrary.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise See http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/431/599. The question is asking of such functionality is available from within blender. It's not, but that doesn't make the question invalid. It just needs a "no" answer.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Yes, obviously it has **nothing** to do with blender! Would you like a declation at the top so people ask you what features you would _allow_ them to use? http://opensource.com/life/15/1/current-state-linux-video-editing

And VP9 **so** obscure! Clearly **no** web platforms are even thinking about **completely** switching to it! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K6JshvblIcM

Comment: @PostasagUest Dude! Chill out o.O 

It is a feature request, as such it should be closed. It is not about Blender's current functionality at all.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise I think everybody missed the imperial ruling where you also had to approve what questions will be asked and answered on stackexchange. Rendering is a **current functionality** if you haven't used Blender ever.

Comment: @PostasagUest **Exporting to a specific file type is a feature request**, you do not need to be mean (or sarcastic, which comes across the same way in text), this community is not about that.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible.

You should use Blender as a [Frame Server](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc_talk:2.6/Manual/Render/Output/Frameserver) and then use another Encoding software to do the job for you. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

For anyone looking at this since the release of 2.80 may be interested to know that WebM is now supported.

https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Import_Export#Images_and_Video